# CakePhp Refreshing page

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have the following problem in Cakephp:
I maded a CMS to edit the content of a website with CakePhp. Now when I change the content in my form and I click Save then he shows again the data from before the form was changed. 
In the database everything saved well and if I refresh the page also he shows the right data.

I know I can render a new page or redirect to another page, but I liked to just show a message with setFlash and that's it. Someone can help me out?

Thanks in advance

Aäron

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Update : check the Justin T. solution below.

You can just redirect to the same page:

to set your flash message:

```
$this->setFlash('blablablabla');
```

and

```
return $this->redirect($this->here); //cake 1.3
```

or

```
return $this->redirect($this->request->here); // cake 2.x
```

or

```
return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'MyController', 'action' => 'methodOfController']); // cake3.X
```

to redirect.

Comment: Nice! Yes it's the request parameter I forgot. Thanks

Comment: Use the Router :: url method to write the url in the redirect method or write the url manually adding subdirectories, there are also some options in the configuration for Cakephp to manages the case of subdirectories

Comment: One can also redirect to $this->referer() as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16342239/421063

Answer (score 2):

With the [new method flash()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3aflash) you set a message **and** redirect in the same method.

*This is the most elegant way I know of*, and it goes something like this :

```
<?php
public function post() {
   // process content here...


   // redirects the user immediately with a nice message
   $this->flash('Your post has been updated, thanks', 'index');

}
```

Hope this helps !