# How to go back to referer page in CakePHP after login

Tags: cakephp, authentication, session-variables, referrer

I have a problem on going back to referer page:

```
first url: http://site.com/venue/apartments/1564/venue-name
referer url: null
```

In this page I can edit stuff inside, so I have a `login` button to go to the login page, after a successful login, I would like to turn back to the `first url`.

```
second url: http://site.com/users/login
referer url: http://site.com/venue/apartments/1564/venue-name
```

when I try to login, due to the CakePHP action rules, i have to refresh the login page to check the credentials, the `problem` starts here:

```
third url: http://site.com/users/login
referer url: http://site.com/users/login
```

by refreshing the page, and checking the credentials in the `login` action of `users` controller I get as refer the same page where I was before, and now I can't going back to the `first url`.

I tried some solution by setting a session variable in the AppController which checks if I'm not in the `login` action page and doing this:

```
AppController.php

public function beforeFilter () {
    $this->setRedirect();
}

public function setRedirect () {
    if ($this->request->params['controller'] != 'users' && $this->request->params['action'] != 'login') {
        $this->Session->write('redir', array('controller'=>$this->request->params['controller'], 'action'=>$this->request->params['action'], implode($this->request->params['pass'], '/')));
    }
}
```

By testing the session var with `debug($this->Session->write('redir'));` everything would seem to works perfect until I go to the `login` action:

```
UsersController.php

public function login () {
    if ($this->request->is ('post')){
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $redir = $this->Session->read('redir');
            if (!empty($redir)) {
                $this->redirect ($redir);
            } else {
                $this->redirect ($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this break the application and if I `debug($redir);` var i get:

```
array(
    'controller' => 'js',
    'action' => 'jquery',
    (int) 0 => 'plugin/jquery.validata.1.7.min' // just a jquery plugin loaded in default.ctp
)
```

instead of

```
array(
    'controller' => 'venue',
    'action' => 'apartments',
    (int) 0 => '1564/venue-name'
)
```

If I `debug($redir);` in any other view of the entire site, everything works well and I get the right data.

I thought in some kind of Session protection routine for `$this->Auth->login()` action but it's totally nonsense for me.

How can I just redirect the user logged to the last page which isn't the `login` view page?

Comment: So, what you want to do is redirect the user to the login form when they try to access a page that requires auth, and then redirect them to that page when auth is successful?

Comment: yes, it is, I haven't found a right way to do it.

Comment: I'm guessing you know that the `Auth` component has this functionality built in. Just do `$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());` within the `if ($this->Auth->login()) {` block. Is there a reason why you're not doing that?

Comment: Yeah, it was my first try, but I have the login problem, once the action login is called for the second time to check the user credentials the referer is the view login instead of the previous one. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but i don't know what it is.

Comment: @VittorioVittori I understand what you're saying, but the `Auth` component takes that into account. Have a look at [the code](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/auth-component#l-302) to see for yourself. Incidentally, your code shouldn't be trying to access a JavaScript file through CakePHP. Does going directly to the JavaScript file in your browser (e.g. http://www.example.com/js/jquery/plugin/jquery.validata.1.7.min.js ) work? Are you using Apache and do you have "mod_rewrite" enabled?

Comment: In facts, there is something wrong, I have `Apache` and `mod_rewrite` loaded, my `WordPress` installations works perfect with it, also my `CakePHP` app works but I get this message in the homepage: `URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server` instead I'm using it in the rest of the application.

Comment: @Nick I've fixed every configuration of the web server and restarted it, but the problem stand still. `mod_rewrite` works but I get this problem in the homepage, and also the problem you mentioned. I'm working on a `XAMPP` server on a `Mac` and this is the only one weird thing I've saw of the server.

Comment: After various tries, now it's just my CakePHP app won't work, every page returns a `404 error`, have I to `configure something` to let mod_rewrite works in cake app? The rest of the server sites (most of them are WordPress sites) works perfect.

Comment: If it's that badly screwed up, you may want to start over. I suggest you download a fresh copy of CakePHP (make sure it's the same version as what you're using now). If you don't already have [Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835) installed, install it so that you have FileMerge too (located in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications). Then use it to compare your copy of CakePHP with the fresh copy so that you can reapply your changes selectively.

Comment: I've fixed the 404 error but the `mod_rewrite` alert still here, `updating the core` gives the `same error`, trying a fully `new installation works`, I don't understand where I've started the problem. It must be something in the `app` folder, so I cannot delete stuff!

Comment: Yep, I tried to overwrite the new installation and seeing where's the problem folder by folder, it seems something in the `View` folder. I'll write where was the problem once I find it.

Comment: The first request to login that has the right referer is done via GET.  So use that to set the 'redirect_after_login' variable to session. The  second request to the login action would be with POST read that variable from the session, clear it and redirect to it. You can check what method used for request with `$this->request->is('post')` or `$this->request->is('get')`.

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried this: `$this->redirect(Controller::referer());`?

I'd have to reread your whole question to be sure, but this should also work: `$this->redirect( $this->referer() );`

Answer (score 11):

I used sessions to keep the last url accessed and if the login is successful the user will be redirected to it.

First in AppController.php I save in session the url, except for login and logout actions:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $url = Router::url(NULL, true); //complete url
    if (!preg_match('/login|logout/i', $url)){
        $this->Session->write('lastUrl', $url);
    }
}
```

In the UserController.php for login action I have the following code:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            if ($this->Session->read('lastUrl')){
                $this->redirect($this->Session->read('lastUrl'));
                exit;
            }else{
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it just like this:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Session->read('referer'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Não foi possível efetuar o login. Usuário ou senha inválidos'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
        }
    } else {
         $this->Session->write('referer', $this->referer());
    }
}
```